# How could I build a basic 'English calculator' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, method-chaining

So I'm currently training in Ruby on the excellent [CodeWars](http://www.codewars.com/) website and have run into a problem that is a bit above my level, but feels like it could really help my coding development if I could look at the/an answer and push it around my brain for a bit. A sort of missing link type deal.

The problem is how to build the Calc class to achieve the following results:

```
class Calc
end

Calc.new.one.plus.two             # Should return 3
Calc.new.five.minus.six           # Should return -1
Calc.new.seven.times.two          # Should return 14
Calc.new.nine.divided_by.three    # Should return 3
```

The class only needs to deal with single digit inputs zero-nine and the + - * / operators, and the format will always be a chain of 3 methods as you see above (i.e. number operator number).

I'd love to read some of your solutions and, if you can be bothered, the thought processes you went through in solving it. Thanks!

Comment: While I think this is a good question in general (and an interesting problem), unfortunately Stackoverflow isn't really the place for a fairly broad question like this. SO is really more for specific questions and answers; things that can be answered concisely, and such. I think you may have more luck with this on a forum of some sort, perhaps. Alternatively, you can try some ideas, and if you run in to a problem or a specific question that has not already been answered here before, you can definitely post that.

Comment: This is more of a request for a discussion than an answerable question, and as @teeg says, is against the purpose of Stackoverflow

Comment: I have solved this kata on codewars, and asking the whole kata as a question on SO defeats the purpose of attempting the kata at all, you should attempt the kata, and when you have issues, post what issues you have

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution, but meets the requirements:

```
class Calc
  ENGLISH_TO_OP = Hash[%i{zero one two three four five six seven eight nine}
    .each_with_index.to_a].merge(plus: :+, minus: :-, times: :*, divided_by: :/)

  def method_missing(m)
    if s = ENGLISH_TO_OP[m]
      (@cmd ||= []) << s
      return @cmd[0].send(*@cmd[1..2]) if @cmd.size == 3
      self
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Which allows:

```
2.1.0 :015 > Calc.new.seven.times.two
 => 14 
2.1.0 :016 > Calc.new.nine.divided_by.three
 => 3 
2.1.0 :017 > Calc.new.five.minus.six
 => -1 
2.1.0 :018 > Calc.new.one.plus.two
 => 3
```

I didn't want to write a lot of code, so `method_missing` beats having to define methods, even though it can be problematic therefore I tend to avoid it. A hash lookup is good for the specified operands and operations, and `each_with_index` could populate values. Assigning the looked up value to s in the conditional was just laziness. Finally, I could have initialized `@cmd` in an initializer, but this is less code and would guard against `@cmd` being reset to nil by another method later.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
class Calc
  attr_accessor :result, :last_operator

  def initialize(result=0)
   @result = result
  end

  OPERATORS = {
    :plus => :+, :minus => :-, :times => :*, :divided_by => :/
  }

  OPERANDS = [ :zero, :one, :two, :three, :four, :five, :six, :seven, :eight, :nine, :ten, :eleven, :twelve ] 

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    if OPERATORS.include?(m.to_sym)
      @last_operator = m.to_sym
      return self 
    elsif OPERANDS.include?(m.to_sym)
      if @last_operator.nil?
        @result = OPERANDS.index(m.to_sym)
        return self
      end
      @result = eval("#{@result} #{OPERATORS[@last_operator]} #{OPERANDS.index(m.to_sym)}")
      return @last_operator.nil? ? self : @result
    end

    super
  end
end


[20] pry(main)> Calc.new.three.times.seven
=> 21
[21] pry(main)> Calc.new.twelve.divided_by.two
=> 6
```

Comment: This will print the value without having to call an external method. If you wish to nest more calls, you'd have to do method_missing for fixnum, and might have to overwrite "times" (because fixnum already have times) .. This solution answers your problem fully though =)

Comment: Haha.. I'm sure you're gonna end up making something crazy simple! (check @GarySWeaver 's solution below)

Comment: He considered the operators as all binary operators.

Comment: Yea.. He used a different (interesting) way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the methods will not be used in an invalid way:

```
class Calc
  def self.operand name, v
    define_method(name) do
      @operator ? @operand.send(@operator, v) : (@operand = v; self)
    end
  end
  def self.operator name, v
    define_method(name) do
      @operator = v; self
    end
  end

  operand :one, 1
  operand :two, 2
  ...
  operator :plus, :+
  operator :minus, :-
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one more trick using [`#method_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) :

```
class Calc
    attr_reader :val
    def initialize
      # operand hash
      @hsh_num = {one: 1,two: 2, three: 3,four: 4,five: 5,six: 6}
      # operator hash
      @hsh_op = {plus: '+', minus: '-',times: '*',divided_by: '/'}
    end
    def method_missing(symbol)
      if @hsh_num[symbol]
        @val = @meth.is_a?(Method) ? @meth.call(@hsh_num[symbol]) : @hsh_num[symbol]
      end
      if @hsh_op[symbol]
        @meth = @val.method(@hsh_op[symbol])
      end
      self
    end
end

# I just added one more method val, to get the last output.
# a bit change I did.
Calc.new.one.plus.two.plus.two.val # => 3
Calc.new.five.minus.six.val # => -1
```

I didn't implement it for all. But you can get an idea from this, for your case.

Comment: Yup, very easy with a `val` call in the end :-)

Comment: @Abdo `self` is main idea there, I am returning it after each method call. :) Then last `val` is just as *pressing equal* to sign on the calculator.

Comment: I don't think `self` is the main idea when you can't use `val` (because in the end, you can't return the expected output)

Comment: @Abdo That's actually my life saver.. :) How can I improve it ?

Comment: haha :-) You will have to limit the endless chaining to three (or else, will have to monkeypatch Fixnum)... Check my code below =)

Comment: btw, I'd rather do a solution like yours where you can chain for ever and call `.val` in the end (this is how I did it first :-) )

Comment: @Abdo Yeah! I don't want to monkeypatch the `Fixnum` class. Thus I did it this way by returning `self`, at the end. Because `self` was tracking everything and saved into right variables..and `val` will give the all.

Comment: yup... This is why I limited the number of chains: if I return a number in the beginning, I'll be forced to call `Fixnum`. This is why I'm checking if I'm reaching the second operand and returning the `Fixnum` then.